# Exporting terrain (elevation) raster data and output is not specified pixel size using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am new to Google Earth Engine, and this is likely a simple solution, but I cannot seem to figure it out. I am using Google Earth Engine to export a 30m elevation raster tiff file bounded by my area of interest. Within the Export.image.toDrive() function, I set the scale to 30, maxPixels to 1e12 since the area of interest exceeds the maximum GEE has set, yet my output has a cell size of 0.00026949459. From GEE video tutorials and StackExchange posts, I haven't seen anyone add additional functions or discuss steps to ensure the cell size stays as specified to export terrain raster datasets. My end goal is to have an exported raster tiff file of my area of interest with a 30-meter cell size.

My GEE code:

````
var elevation = ee.Image("USGS/NED");
//Map.addLayer(elevation)

// Create a geometry representing an export region. [R, B, L, T]
var aoi = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-106.067341, 41.725516, -111.162722, 45.050258]);
//Map.addLayer(aoi)

// Export the image, specifying scale and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: elevation,
  description: 'DEM30_ned',
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e12,
  region: aoi,
});```
````

Answer (score 3):

Your code seems to be working correctly. The exported image has a resolution of 30m (see attached image) in GCS_North_American_1983 Spatial Reference which approximates to 0.000269 decimal degrees in a cylindrical projection.

[image]